# Tcl/Tk log file has many ^H characters when called by a Jenkins job

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I have a Tcl/Tk expect script, and log information is logged to external log file.

I can execute it on Linux server successfully without any wrong, and the log file do not have any weird `^H`. But when the script is called by Jenkins job, run on the same Linux server. the log file will have a lot of `^H`, And the expect will timeout.

What the possible reason could be?

Comment: What is the ASCII value of ^H? It might be a \r\n issue, though you don't deal with Windows, so maybe not.

Comment: Thank you Sashoalm. I am run it on Linux. the value is \u0008.

Comment: Create a minimal example that reproduces the error and post it. See http://sscce.org.

Comment: I am not sure how the ^H is passed to my script. I am not able to generate a small example for this issue . It seems the jenkins job implemented a waitbar along with capture the real time output. That maybe the reason. I tried to implement a waitbar myself.But can not cause the same problem.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem reliably, then how can anyone know how to solve it? Imagine you're on a friends computer with a clean installation of Linux. Describe step by step what software you need to install and run to get a file with those ^H symbols.

Answer (score 2):

The `^H` is actually the [backspace character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace), U+000008, and it is used in terminals (and terminal emulators) to move the current character insertion position one place to the left. This is used in turn to simulate various kinds of effects, such as making a character bold (by double-striking) or giving it an underline (by putting a `_` on the same cell). Think like it's going to a traditional teletype, which prints things into the same position twice. It's definitely a hang-over from
the old days.

It seems that Jenkins (or maybe whatever it is calling, quite possibly maven though *definitely* not necessarily!) is using that device to back up over what it has written so it can write a new value there instead, probably for something like a simple download progress meter. Things that are writing to what they think is a terminal sometimes do this. You'll just have to cope. A `\b` in your Expect regular expressions will match it, though it is possibly unwise to do so, as whatever is being overwritten is transient info. If the characters are being written to a file, the `col` program (part of the `nroff`/`groff` suite) can be used to strip them; that *might* be easier.

Be aware that there are other ways that software can achieve the same effect, such as writing just a carriage return (which puts the cursor back at the start of the *current* line).

Comment: Thank you Donal. But I am still not clear how to fix it.
Here is the output I got.
cd /iris/home/blackBox                         ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HTesting/disable_session_t^M^M<g# cd /iris/home/blackBoxTesting/disable_session_tr                         ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hack^M
<:/iris/home/blackBoxTesting/disable_session_track#
timeout while communicating with probe

I am expect a prompt as "iris@$prompt", What can I do for it?